# Serialized array in controller

Tags: magento-1.9, controllers, json, unserialize

This is my script

```
<script>
function callAjax(){
    var customoptionhtml = document.getElementById("customoption-dynamic").innerHTML; //alert(test);//alert(jQuery(test).text());
    var subtotalhtml = jQuery('.price-wrap').html();//alert(innerHtml);
     jQuery.ajax({
        type    : "POST",
        url     : "<?php echo Mage::getUrl('module/controller/action'); ?>",
        data    : jQuery('#product_addtocart_form').serialize(),
        data    : { customoption: customoptionhtml,formser:jQuery('#product_addtocart_form').serialize(),subtotal:subtotalhtml } ,
        dataType: "json",
        complete: function(response) {   
            //action        
        },
    });
}
</script>
```

This is my controller

```
public function testAction() {
        $product = $this->getRequest()->getParam('formser');
        $customoption = $this->getRequest()->getParam('customoption');


        $pdctname = $product['product'];
        Mage::log($product, null, '1.log');
        Mage::log($customoption, null, '2.log');

}
```

I got **$product** in log file as :

> form_key=ZWdfUerRFgl9oR4r&**product=1**&related_product=&options%5B9%5D=tryty&options%5B10%5D=85&options%5B11%5D=132&options%5B12%5D=156&options%5B13%5D=181&options%5B16%5D=&options%5B17%5D=&options%5B19%5D=&options%5B18%5D=&options%5B14%5D=183&options%5B15%5D=&name=ry&companyname=ty&email=test%40test.com&phnmbr=7894561233

I want to get "**product=1**"(marked in bold) from the above data(that is the product id).

I tried as `$pdctdet = $product['product'];` .But not working.

Please give a solution.

Comment: You can try with json_decode($product) and let me know which output is display.

Comment: I have used $decodedata =json_decode($product);Mage::log("test".$decodedata, null, 'today1.log');
Gives output as "test".Decode array is not getting

Comment: you can try with unserialize method of php and let me know

Comment: $unserializedData = array(); Mage::log(parse_str($unserializedData,$product), null, 'today5.log');

But not working.Please give a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Use this in your controller:

```
$data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
parse_str($data['formser']);
$productid = $product;
```

**"product=1"** will be in $productid variable.

Answer (score 0):

As per your log `$product` contains as a string. if you need `$productId` then you need to convert this string like below.

```
$product = "form_key=ZWdfUerRFgl9oR4r&product=1&related_product=&options%5B9%5D=tryty&options%5B10%5D=85&options%5B11%5D=132&options%5B12%5D=156&options%5B13%5D=181&options%5B16%5D=&options%5B17%5D=&options%5B19%5D=&options%5B18%5D=&options%5B14%5D=183&options%5B15%5D=&name=ry&companyname=ty&email=test%40test.com&phnmbr=7894561233";

$products = explode("&",$product);
foreach($products as $string){
    list($k, $v) = explode('=', $string);
    $result[ $k ] = $v; 
}
echo $productId = $result['product']; // 1
```